# Terminate SSIS package after specific time interval

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

We are scheduling SSIS packages using Windows Task Scheduler. Every hour the scheduled task will create a new instance of package and start its execution. We need to make sure that previous instance is terminated before next execution starts. Is it possible to terminate package execution from with-in package itself after specific time interval?

Comment: There might be a way if you run it as a SQL agent job. Not sure if that would be possible using Windows Task Scheduler.

Comment: Why aren't you using the SQL Agent to run your package as a job? This would be handled automatically.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Our operational team find SQL agent to be more difficult to manage and migrate from server to server. We also cannot maintain SQL agent jobs in TFS as schema so it is more difficult to detect and manage changes.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Task Scheduler, if you go to the "Settings" tab of your task, there is a checkbox with the option to "Stop the task if it runs longer than:".

Set this to the desired time interval, and Task Scheduler will kill the process when the specified time is elapsed.

[image: Example of the setting in the Task Scheduler]

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Will SSIS package be able to intercept this process termination event and perform any cleanup task? I need to ensure the integrity of data as well in case of package termination.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea :-) I *think* it will just kill DTExec, which will stop your package in its tracks, but I'm not 100%. I tend to use SQL Server Agent myself, with all packages stored in an SSIS catalogue (2012). Best thing I can suggest is to give it a go in your staging environment and see how it behaves.  The other alternative, as others suggest above, is to investigate moving to SQL Agent.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Our operational team find SQL agent to be more difficult to manage and migrate from server to server. We also cannot maintain SQL agent jobs in TFS as schema so it is more difficult to detect and manage changes